# What C datatype should be used for an array which will contain 2-digit HEXADECIMAL values?

Tags: c, arrays, types, compiler-errors

I have the following array in a program I am trying to debug:

```
static u8 info3[LEN] = {
  06,
  07,
  04,
  00,
  00,
  01,
  00,
  0e,
  03
};
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
test.c(45): error C2021: expected exponent value, not ','
```

and line#45 is the line containing **`0e,`**. According to [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/986k91hd.aspx) resource,

> expected exponent value, not 'character'
>
> The character used as the exponent of a **floating-point constant** is not
>   a valid number. Be sure to use an exponent that is in range.

This tells me that the compiler thinks that the compiler thinks that `info3` contains Floating Point values. But the values there are actually 2-digit hexadecimal numbers.

So the question is that which datatype should be used here for the values stored in this array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `0x` at these numbers.
For example, `0x01, 0x0e`, or the compiler won't treat them as hexadecimal.

And the reason it expect exponent value after `e` is because you can use scientific notation in C, for example `float var = 1.54334E-34`.

Answer (score 2):

To write hexadecimal numbers in C, you write `0x` followed by hex digits. So two-digit hex numbers in C would look like

```
0x6a
0x0e
0xff
0x29
0xbc
```

When you write `0e` the compiler complains because an `e` in that position indicates "times 10 to the". For example

35e22

means 35 times 10 to the 22 power and

1e9

is one billion (one times ten to the 9th power).

If you write

```
0e
```

It looks like zero times ten to the........  and the compiler complains because you did not give the exponent.

Comment: Leading 0 means the numbers are octal so even 09 would fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

In C any constant preceded by 0 is an **octal constant**.  So, `015` is octal `15` and is decimal `13`. Also `08` is invalid as no octal no can have a value greater than 8.

If you want **hexadecimal constants**, you should use `0x08`, `0x0a` etc.